# create a webview in a view controller to open a url with swift 2 xcode 7.2

Tags: uiwebview, swift2, xcode7.2

I have created a viewcontroller called communityViewController and connected it to its class with the same name. Then I added a webview in man.storyboard. How do i configure it now in the .swift file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class communityViewController:UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://example.de/");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add in your info.plist

```
<dict>
   <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
   <dict/>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
   </dict>
</plist>
```